# Redirect subdomain to different locations based on url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a website on a domain that I want to move to another domain. Here is my problem. The root URL has to redirect to a different location on the new domain. Example:

```
http://subdomain.olddomain.com/ must redirect to http://www.newdomain.com/location

http://subdomain.olddomain.com/code/slug must redirect to http://www.newdomain.com/slug
```

The htaccess code that I have doesn't work ver

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This code works for the second example, but nog on the first. Can anyone help me setup the correct htaccess code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^code/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newdomain.com/location [L,R]
```

Comment: Tnx, that seems to do the trick :). I will accept your awnser in 1 minute